# Facebook share button code snippet

Tags: facebook, magento, button, share

Does anyone know  how to create  facebook share button? I need it to be the horizontal version at about 15-20 pixels high. They seem to have dropped any documentation in favour of the like button but I would like both. I can only seem to  find wordpress plugins but i simply need the code snippet.

Any help would be appreciated... thankyou

Glynn
Roco Clothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it using javascript sdk :

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: appId, status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

    $("#Pst").click(function shareWithFacebook() {
        FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish',
            message: 'message',
            user_message_prompt: 'message',
            attachment: {
                name: 'message',
                caption: 'message',
                description: ('message'),
                href: 'http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg',
                media: [{ 'type': 'image', 'src': 'http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg', 'href': 'http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg'}]
            },
            action_links: [{ text: ' Name ', href: 'http://www.destination360.com/europe/sweden/images/s/sweden-visby.jpg'}]
        },
         function (response) {
             if (response && response.post_id) {
                 // Do some custom action after the user successfully
                 // posts this to their wall
                 alert('Thanks for sharing!');
             }
         }
        );
        return false;
    });

<div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="Pst" onclick="return shareWithFacebook();"  >
        Share
    </a>
```

if you want to do it using plugin  and would you please mark it as answered :) :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

you will find the code like that :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=137344766349901&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="www.eslamsoliman.uk.cm" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

change your link :)

Answer (score 0):

The Share button is deprecated although still functional.
The current recommended way to implement sharing from a website is via the [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [Send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) (which is also usually paired with the Like button but works standalone).

If you must use the old share button for some reason, the documentation is no longer available on the Developer site, but there's a third party example here: http://www.wpcode.net/add-share-button.html/ (it should work on any site, not just Wordpress blogs)